# apt-get upgrade with /usr/bin on aufs fails to create backup link

Tags: mount, apt, perl, dpkg, aufs

I'm trying to update a frugal persistent (root and home) install of antiX-15 x64 from stable to testing.

I changed the source lists and ran `apt-get update`.

`apt-get upgrade` then fails with the following error:

```
Unpacking perl (5.20.2-6) over (5.20.2-3+deb8u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.20.2-6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/bin/psed' before installing new version: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.20.2-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.20.2-6) over (5.20.2-3+deb8u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.20.2-6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of `./usr/bin/perl5.20.2' before installing new version: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.20.2-6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.20.2-6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to check and/or remove extended attributes (as described here [What means "unable to make backup link of /binary before installing new version: No such file or directory"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120964/what-means-unable-to-make-backup-link-of-binary-before-installing-new-version)), but lsattr and chattr don't work on aufs.

Comment: I don't see why the use of aufs is relevant. Just check that you can indeed move the link.